# Query error SQL Compact Edition 3.5

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

In my solution I have a local database and a database connect class with a GetQuery function. This function works good but for some reason, it won't handle the query as shown below. When I run a query like `SELECT * FROM logs` everything works out, but when I try to use this query instead

```
SELECT klantnr AS 'Klantnummer', 
       klantnaam AS 'Klantnaam', 
       vraag AS 'Vraag/probleem',
       informatie AS 'Informatie/uitvoering', 
       antwoord AS 'Antwoord/oplossing', 
       datum AS 'Datum', 
       tijd AS 'Tijd' 
FROM logs
```

I get the following error message: `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 21,Token in error = Klantnummer ]`

Comment: Try without surrounding with `'`, example: `klantnr AS Klantnummer`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it doesn't work ether.

Comment: I think because there are `/` characters in the query.

Comment: What if you replace the / with another character? Or surround them with [ ] ?

Comment: but error indicates `Klantnummer` token

Comment: I know, when i use the ' but when I remove those ' I get the following message: `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 70,Token in error = / ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT klantnr AS [Klantnummer], 
       klantnaam AS [Klantnaam], 
       vraag AS [Vraag/probleem],
       informatie AS [Informatie/uitvoering], 
       antwoord AS [Antwoord/oplossing], 
       datum AS [Datum], 
       tijd AS [Tijd] 
FROM logs
```